# select multiple rows on Janus GridEX

Tags: c#, winforms, janus, gridex

I want to select multiple rows on Janus GridEX, but selectedItems property cannot be assigned and it's read only.
however I can select a specific row by GridEX.Row and set the current selected row, but I cant add a row or any thing like that to select multiple row!

Can anyone help me

Thanks alot, Shahin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First make sure that your grid allows selecting multiple rows. This can either be set in the designer or in code.

```
gridEX1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultipleSelection;
```

Now to select rows, use SelectedItems.Add(position) where position is the index of the row in the grid.

```
GridEXRow row1 = ...;
GridEXRow row2 = ...;
gridEX1.SelectedItems.Add(row1.Position);
gridEX1.SelectedItems.Add(row2.Position);
```